# Shaka Player does not adapt bitrate

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, mpeg-dash, shaka, adaptive-bitrate

We're using Shaka player with the default configuration and it's good - but I'm not seeing any adaption into lower bitrates and still seeing buffering. We're also getting a pause at the start where it freezes on the first frame for 2 seconds then there is a rate change event and it plays.

I've manipulated this in the player to change the baseUrls because we preload the manifests.

Here is an example MPD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd" type="static" minBufferTime="PT10S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-main:2011" mediaPresentationDuration="PT34.389S">
  <Period start="PT0S" duration="PT34.389S" id="1">
    <AdaptationSet mimeType="video/mp4" frameRate="60000/1001" segmentAlignment="true" subsegmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1" bitstreamSwitching="false">
      <Representation id="1" width="2048" height="1152" bandwidth="7200000" codecs="avc1.4d4032">
        <BaseURL>https://localhost:3000/assets/org/1/collection/147/a36c46d6-745f-4b6e-99bd-486a1c43342b/cmaf.0.9.H_264.cmfv</BaseURL>
        <SegmentBase indexRange="760-1015">
          <Initialization range="0-759"/>
        </SegmentBase>
      </Representation>
      <Representation id="2" width="2048" height="1152" bandwidth="7200000" codecs="hev1.1.6.L150.B0">
        <BaseURL>https://localhost:3000/assets/org/1/collection/147/a36c46d6-745f-4b6e-99bd-486a1c43342b/cmaf.0.9.H_265.cmfv</BaseURL>
        <SegmentBase indexRange="708-963">
          <Initialization range="0-707"/>
        </SegmentBase>
      </Representation>
      <Representation id="3" width="2048" height="1152" bandwidth="5600000" codecs="avc1.4d4032">
        <BaseURL>https://localhost:3000/assets/org/1/collection/147/a36c46d6-745f-4b6e-99bd-486a1c43342b/cmaf.0.7.H_264.cmfv</BaseURL>
        <SegmentBase indexRange="760-1015">
          <Initialization range="0-759"/>
        </SegmentBase>
      </Representation>
      <Representation id="4" width="2048" height="1152" bandwidth="4000000" codecs="avc1.4d4032">
        <BaseURL>https://localhost:3000/assets/org/1/collection/147/a36c46d6-745f-4b6e-99bd-486a1c43342b/cmaf.0.5.H_264.cmfv</BaseURL>
        <SegmentBase indexRange="759-1014">
          <Initialization range="0-758"/>
        </SegmentBase>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
    <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" lang="eng" segmentAlignment="0">
      <Representation id="5" bandwidth="96000" audioSamplingRate="48000" codecs="mp4a.40.2">
        <BaseURL>https://localhost:3000/assets/org/1/collection/147/a36c46d6-745f-4b6e-99bd-486a1c43342b/cmaf.0.audio.cmfa</BaseURL>
        <SegmentBase indexRange="658-913">
          <Initialization range="0-657"/>
        </SegmentBase>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
  </Period>
</MPD>
```

Here is the config for ABR

[image]

Any pointers how to get the video running super smooth and quick?

Comment: Do you have the maxWidth restriction set to something? I think the AbrManager has no problem selecting higher resolutions than the player size. See [this issue](https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/2333).